# Find the value of $\frac{1}{(pq)​^2​-10r^2​+300}+\frac{1}{(qr)​^2​-10p^2​+300}+\frac{1}{(pr)​^2​-10q^2​+300}$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, roots, symmetric-polynomials, cubics

> If $p+q+r=6,pq+pr+qr=8,pqr=2$, what is the value of:
> $$\frac{1}{(pq)​^2​-10r^2​+300}+\frac{1}{(qr)​^2​-10p^2​+300}+\frac{1}{(pr)​^2​-10q^2​+300}$$

I tried to change $\frac{1}{(pq)​^2​-10r^2​+300}$ to $\frac{1}{\frac{4}{r^2}​-10r^2​+300}$ but I don't know how to solve it.

Please provide a hint.

Comment: this is a very intersting problem where did you get it?

Comment: @DhrdzEartep We recently had several users posting problems from the ongoing 2020 Polish Mathematical Olympiad. This problem is not from another ongoing contest, is it?

Comment: Is the result $25/1702$?

Answer (score 3):

$p$, $q$ and $r$ are roots of the equation:
$$x^3-6x^2+8x-2=0,$$ which by your work gives:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{p^2q^2-10r^2+300}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{r^2}{4-10r^4+300r^2}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{r^2}{2(r^3-6r^2+8r)-10r^4+300r^2}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{r}{16+288r+2r^2-10r^3}=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}\frac{r}{8(r^3-6r^2+8r)+288r+2r^2-10r^3}=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{r^2+23r-176}.$$
Can you end it now?

For example, I got
$$\prod_{cyc}(r^2+23r-176)=(pqr)^2+pqr(23(pq+pr+qr)+881(p+q+r)+24311)+$$
$$+30976(p+q+r)^2-176(pq+pr+qr)^2+712448(p+q+r)-$$
$$-4048(p+q+r)(pq+pr+qr)-155056(pq+pr+qr)-5451776=$$
$$=-1448162.$$